# Problem JSLink (color priorities) - Nothing changes

Tags: list, javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering, append-changes

I have a problem using JSLink. The goal is to color in red, orange, green the priority field. For information, I followed step-by-step the [tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd) given by Microsoft.

1. In Site Features, I've ACTIVATED the 'SharePoint Server Publication'
2. In Site Settings, I click on 'Master Page'. It send me to the master page gallery (on site collection). I added my .js, following this [tutorial](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/31/uploading-javascript-js-files-as-javascript-display-template-in-sharepoint-2013/), with the following information:

   - JavaScript display template
   - target type = View
   - standalone = Override
   - target scope = `/site_collection/etc/etc/mysite/mylistview.aspx`

   And finally 'Publish' to validate.
3. In my list view, I click to modify the web part, and under Miscellaneous, in JS field, I add the link to the JS file in the masterpage. Ie, `/site_collection/etc/masterpage/colorpriority.js`
4. After that, I close the file, but nothing happens !

Comment: If you edit the web part after setting the JSLink property, does it stick? Or does it revert?  If it sticks, try running IE Dev tools when loading the page, and see if any errors are occurring.  And can you share code?

Comment: Also, just to speed up your CSR efforts, use Cisar by Andrei Markeev. You'll get instant results with that.

Comment: Link to [extension](https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar) that @uberz91 mentions

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered, tom, Keeps StackOverflow clean

Answer (score 2):

It is

```
~sitecollection/etc/masterpage/colorpriority.js
```

You have

```
/site_collection/etc/masterpage/colorpriority.js
```

#### Must read for all CSR developers:

http://spdevlab.com/2013/07/07/5-facts-about-jslink-in-sharepoint-2013-you-might-not-know/

#### Alternative: Color using a Calculated Column

FYI, You can also Color based on Priority using a Calculated Column
No need for Scriptfiles & JSlink

Create a Calculated Column, set datatype to Number

```
=[Priority]
&IF([Task Status]="Not Started" , "" ,
  "<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
    &"var row=this;while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode}"
    &"row.style.backgroundColor='#"
    &CHOOSE( RIGHT( LEFT( [Priority] , 2) , 1) , "fab" , "fda" , "9fa" )
  &"'}"">" 
)
```

Detailed explanation at: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Comment: ~sitecollection/etc